# Gradle raises an error when using annotationProcessor: Circular dependency between the following tasks

Tags: java, gradle, annotations, build.gradle

I'm trying to create a multi-project build with Gradle with the following projects structure:

```
Root project 'optget'
+--- Project ':og-annotation'
+--- Project ':og-apps'
|    +--- Project ':og-apps:ast'
|    +--- Project ':og-apps:ref'
|    \--- Project ':og-apps:run'
\--- Project ':og-processors'
     +--- Project ':og-processors:ast'
     +--- Project ':og-processors:ref'
     \--- Project ':og-processors:run'
```

The root `build.gradle` sets `repositories` for all projects.

The `og-annotation/build.gradle` file has no dependencies at all and applies only `java-plugin`.

The `og-processors/ast/build.gradle` file has a few dependencies among which there is the `og-annotation` project:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.8'
    implementation project(':og-annotation') // <- using the annotation
    implementation 'com.sun:tools:1.7.0.13'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.8'
}
```

The most interesting and confusing file as for me here is `og-apps/ast/build.gradle` (the `og-apps` directory keeps sample projects that use `og-annotation` and `og-processors` modules):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':og-annotation')
    annotationProcessor project(':og-processors:ast')
}
```

So when I'm trying to build the project I get the following error:

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:og-apps:ast:classes
\--- :og-apps:ast:compileJava
     \--- :og-apps:ast:jar
          \--- :og-apps:ast:classes (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

**The questions:**

- Where there is a circular dependency?
- How can I build the project without of any error?
- Probably is the structure wrong?

I'll be grateful for any interaction :)

Comment: Could you share more of `og-apps/ast/build.gradle` ? It seems that og-apps:ast needs its own jar in order to compile

Comment: @ToYonos thank you for the answer. however i have just resolved the problem. it's pretty strange but it seems that Gradle can't distinguish between `:og-apps:ast` and `:og-processors:ast`. So I have renamed `og-apps:ast` to `og-apps:sample-ast` and it works :)